# New mathematical constant formed by continued fraction with prime numbers?

Tags: prime-numbers, irrational-numbers, continued-fractions

Notational convention:
$$\bigoplus_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k=a_0+\cfrac{1}{a_1+\cfrac{1}{a_2+\cfrac{1}{a_3+\cfrac{1}{\ddots}}}}$$

Let $$ P:=\bigoplus_{k=1}^{\infty}p_k$$

where $p_k$ is the k-th prime number.

Conjecture: $$P=e?$$

Numerical evidence: First terms:

```
  2+1/(3+1/(5+1/(7+1/(11+1/(13+1/(17+1/(19+1/(23+1/(29+1/(31+1/(37+1/(41)))))))))))
=2.313036736433582906383951602640999732416979599998686694360781...
```

Maybe after some time it will converge to 2.718...

What is known about this constant?

Comment: The value of this continued fraction is somewhere between $37/16\approx2.3125$ (what you get by truncating at $a_3=5$) and
$266/115\approx2.31304$ (what you get by truncating at $a_4=7$. Doesn't look like it will be $e$. Why did you think it would?

Comment: The continued fraction of $e$ is known, and it's not the primes. (Apparently, $\tanh(1)=\dfrac{e^2-1}{e^2+1}$'s continued fraction is the odd integers - and I'm not entirely sure why this is - but I've never heard anything about the primes.)

Comment: You should have noticed that the truncated fractions alternately go up and down. This happens to all continued fractions of this type. The proof is left as an exercise.

Comment: The value $0.43233208718590286890925379324199996370511089688\ldots$ is written [here](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/45907402_Continued_fractions_constructed_from_prime_numbers). Edit: This also leads me to [OEIS A084255](https://oeis.org/A084255).

Comment: I've edited the "Let $P=...$" as it was clearly too small to see.

Comment: `=2.313036736433582906383951602640999732416979599998686694360781` if you go further maybe you'll find out that it's equal to $e$? :)

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen That's because they started with 0. OP is referring to the reciprocal.

Comment: See [OEIS A06442](http://oeis.org/A064442).

Comment: This number appears here http://oeis.org/wiki/Continued_fractions

Comment: And you are advised to study [this Wikipage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) for the basics. Also learn the (more or less) standard notation.

Comment: It seems like the number has been considered, but not much—other than its irrationality—is known. (It's irrational because it has an infinite continued fraction.) EDIT: Also the fact that, unfortunately, it is unequal to $e$.

Comment: @columbus8myhw You are right, I wasn't reading carefully enough, but as you said, $[0;2,3,5,7,11,\ldots ]$ and $[2;3,5,7,11,\ldots ]$ are obviously related.

Comment: People usually abbreviate the continued fraction $a_0 + \cfrac1{a_1+\cfrac 1{a_2 +\cdots}}$ as $[a_0; a_1, a_2, \ldots]$.

Answer (score 5):

Continued fractions don't work the way you think they do.  Let $$x =  a_0 + \cfrac1{a_1+\cfrac 1{a_2 +\cdots}},$$ which we will abbreviate as $x = [a_0; a_1, a_2, \ldots]$.  Then probably the most important thing to know about continued fractions is $$a_0 < [a_0; a_1, a_2] < [a_0; a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4] < \ldots < x
< \ldots < [a_0; a_1, a_2, a_3] < [a_0; a_1] $$

Your fraction, $P =[2; 3, 5, 7, 11, \ldots]$ has the property that

$$\frac {37}{16} = [2;3,5] < P < [2;3] = \frac 73$$ 
so we know that $2.3125 < P < 2.333\ldots$ and it is therefore impossible that $P=e$.

Continued fractions converge really fast.  If you compute the first 13 terms and find that the result is approximately 2.31303673, then the result of carrying the fraction to infinity will be some number extremely close to 2.31303673.  It is impossible that the remaining terms could budge the result as far as $2.7$.  There is a theorem that if $x = [a_0; a_1, \ldots]$ and $[a_0; a_1\ldots a_k] = \frac{p_k}{q_k}$, then $$\left\lvert x - \frac{p_k}{q_k}\right\rvert < \frac1{q_kq_{k+1}} < \frac1{q_k^2}.$$  The $q_k$ increase exponentially quickly in relation to $k$, at a rate of at least $\phi^n$, where $\phi = \frac12(1+\sqrt 5)$, so the difference between $x$ and its approximation by a finite continued fraction of length $n$ is at least as fast as $O(\phi^{-2n})$.  The most slowly-converging continued fraction is $[1;1,1,1,1\ldots]$, and you can see for yourself how quickly it converges to its limit, which also happens to be $\phi$.